# Help ID'ing early 90's Lemond

Tags: road-bike

I was wondering if anyone could help me identify this bike, or point me to the resources I could use to get get a better idea about what it is.

--

[Pictures @ Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPhsl.jpg)

[Cross-post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bicycling/comments/8se2ex/help_me_identify_a_greg_lemond_bike_year/)

---

"This seems to be a fairly rare pre-Trek frame, apparently from 1992, going by the serial number. It has pantographed "Greg LeMond" signatures on the rear frame stays, another LeMond signature and "HAND MADE" pantographed on the top of the rear brake bridge, and is stamped "SILVA" on the underside of the rear brake bridge. The BB is stamped with a serial number (25 9237) and 54c, which indicates the size (and Columbus tubing; there's no tubing ID decals and the "SILVA" stamp apparently indicates a frame that was painted in Italy, and not in the U.S. by the importer, as many were when LeMond went belly-up). The chrome dropouts are also stamped "Columbus." There are no model ID decals or other identification marks, as far as I can tell, and I haven't been able to identify it more accurately despite an extensive search."